# Linux Strace in C

Tags: c, linux, size, strace

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

int main(void)
{
int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      fork();
      printf("Hello World\n");
   }
}
```

> 1. How can I use **strace** to find the name of system call
>    of this excutable file.
> 2. How can I use **size** to find the memory of this excutable

I have managed to compile this code into ***a.out*** file
but I don't know which code to use to find system call name
and size

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `a.out`, you can do:

```
strace -ff ./a.out
```

to see all the list of system calls made. Refer [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) for more details.

```
size ./a.out
```

to get the size of various sections in the binary. Refer [size(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/size.1.html) for more details.